# How to add 'on click event' to a QGraphicsView

Tags: qt

I have added a QGraphicsView to my ui form in the Designer. Now I want to add an 'on click event' to this widget.

Comment: What do you mean "click event", do you mean you want customise it's behaviour for when you click on it?

Comment: yes man,,that is the thing that I want...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to subclass a QGraphicsView? If so you could easily handle the cases with something like that:

MyQGraphicsView.h

```
class MyQGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    void enterEvent(QEvent *event);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event);
}
```

MyQGraphicsView.cpp

```
void MyQGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Do what you want
}

//Do the same with all the events.
```